# Python - How to cut a string in Python?

Tags: python, string

Suppose that I have the following string:

```
http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20
```

How can I take off what is after `&` including the `&` and have this string:

```
http://www.domain.com/?s=some
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to split the string:

```
>>> s = 'http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20'
>>> s.split('&')
['http://www.domain.com/?s=some', 'two=20']
```

That will return a list as you can see so you can do:

```
>>> s2 = s.split('&')[0]
>>> print s2
http://www.domain.com/?s=some
```

Answer (score 61):

Well, to answer the immediate question:

```
>>> s = "http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20"
```

The `rfind` method returns the index of right-most substring:

```
>>> s.rfind("&")
29
```

You can take all elements up to a given index with the slicing operator:

```
>>> "foobar"[:4]
'foob'
```

Putting the two together:

```
>>> s[:s.rfind("&")]
'http://www.domain.com/?s=some'
```

---

If you are dealing with URLs in particular, you might want to use built-in libraries that deal with URLs. If, for example, you wanted to remove `two` from the above query string:

First, parse the URL as a whole:

```
>>> import urlparse, urllib
>>> parse_result = urlparse.urlsplit("http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20")
>>> parse_result
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.domain.com', path='/', query='s=some&two=20', fragment='')
```

Take out just the query string:

```
>>> query_s = parse_result.query
>>> query_s
's=some&two=20'
```

Turn it into a `dict`:

```
>>> query_d = urlparse.parse_qs(parse_result.query)
>>> query_d
{'s': ['some'], 'two': ['20']}
>>> query_d['s']
['some']
>>> query_d['two']
['20']
```

Remove the `'two'` key from the dict:

```
>>> del query_d['two']
>>> query_d
{'s': ['some']}
```

Put it back into a query string:

```
>>> new_query_s = urllib.urlencode(query_d, True)
>>> new_query_s
's=some'
```

And now stitch the URL back together:

```
>>> result = urlparse.urlunsplit((
    parse_result.scheme, parse_result.netloc,
    parse_result.path, new_query_s, parse_result.fragment))
>>> result
'http://www.domain.com/?s=some'
```

The benefit of this is that you have more control over the URL. Like, if you always wanted to remove the `two` argument, even if it was put earlier in the query string (`"two=20&s=some"`), this would still do the right thing. It might be overkill depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

```
string = 'http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20'
cut_string = string.split('&')
new_string = cut_string[0]
print(new_string)
```

Comment: This won't work if there are any other ampersands in the URL.

Comment: I answered the question like everyone, he didn't ask for an exception. So to do the example he gave, this is the most simple pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Ah that's true. I thought he asked how to take off the right-most ampersand in a string (so I was thinking would be better if you gave `string.rsplit('&',1)`), but he didn't ask that necessarily.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `find()`

```
>>> s = 'http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20'
>>> s[:s.find('&')]
'http://www.domain.com/?s=some'
```

Of course, if there is a chance that the searched for text will not be present then you need to write more lengthy code:

```
pos = s.find('&')
if pos != -1:
    s = s[:pos]
```

Whilst you can make some progress using code like this, more complex situations demand a true URL parser.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>str = "http://www.domain.com/?s=some&two=20"
>>str.split("&")
>>["http://www.domain.com/?s=some", "two=20"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s[0:"s".index("&")]
```

what does this do:

- take a slice from the string starting at index 0, up to, but not including the index of &in the string.