# How to cut on a specific part of a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

i'm searching for a way to cut my string with a regular expression

for instance, if i have following string

```
abcde.dhsjd.djshdj.(2019).(14856p).abdjskf
```

and i want to get:

```
 abcde dhsjd djshdj 2019
```

i already have following

```
    file_sub = re.sub(r'[\.()]+', ' ', file)
    split_file= re.split(r'[\d+]', file)
```

when i run my code, it cuts off before the 4 digits.
like so:

```
 abcde dhsjd djshdj
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to cut a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247792/python-how-to-cut-a-string-in-python)

Comment: `" ".join(re.split(r'\W+', s)[0:4])`, or `re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', re.sub(r'^((?:[^.]*\.){3}[^.]*).*',  r'\1', s))` or `re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', re.sub(r'^((?:[^.]*\.){3}[^.]*).*',  lambda x: x.group(1).replace(')','').replace('(','').replace('.',''), s))` and many more variations are possible.

Comment: I'd simply match [`^[^)]+`](https://regex101.com/r/hUHe5c/1) and [replace `[.(]+` with space](https://regex101.com/r/hUHe5c/2) in match.

Comment: Now, you just need to use `" ".join(s.split('.')[0:3])`, no regex needed (you may check dot count before running this, e.g. `if s.count('.') > 3:`)

Comment: split and join: `' '.join(x for x in s.split('.') if not x.startswith('('))`

Comment: @Falcjh can you explain why did you not extract `abdjskf` why do you need to stop exactly at `(2019)`? why you don't want the rest of the part what is the condition to extract or ignore a part of the text

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
inp = "abcde.dhsjd.djshdj.(2019).(14856p).abdjskf"
def cb(m):
    return m.group(1).replace('.', ' ') + m.group(2)

output = re.sub('^(.*?)\((\d+)\).*$', cb, inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
abcde dhsjd djshdj 2019
```

The strategy here is to match the first dot separated portion and year in two separate capture groups.  Then, inside the callback function we replace dot with space and concatenate together.